# The multi-part identifier could not be bound error when assigning a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have looked at several posts regarding the cause of this error and they all seem to point to aliases not being used to identify columns.

```
SELECT        JM.Job_Number, JM.Project_Manager, JM.Superintendent, 
ECL.Employee_Name AS PM_Name, ECL2.Employee_Name AS Supt_Name
FROM            SPECTRUM.Spectrum.dbo.JC_JOB_MASTER_MC JM 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SPECTRUM.Spectrum.dbo.Z_EMPLOYEE_CODE_LIST ECL 
            ON LTRIM(RTRIM(JM.Project_Manager)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ECL.Employee_Code)) 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SPECTRUM.Spectrum.dbo.Z_EMPLOYEE_CODE_LIST ECL2 
            ON LTRIM(RTRIM(JM.Superintendent)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ECL2.Employee_Code))


WHERE JM.Company_Code = 'ABC' AND JM.Status_Code = 'A' AND JM.Job_Number = '29-0018-00'

DECLARE
@test varchar(50) = ''

set @test = JM.Project_Manager

PRINT(@test)
```

The select portion of this runs fine but once I add in the `set @test = JM.Project_Manager` line I receive the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does `JM.Project_Manager` come from???

Comment: Based on your comment below, it seems like your question might be a little bit of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you edit it to include some more details? Here's a good place to look for pointers: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the variable in the `select` statement:

```
DECLARE @test varchar(50) = '';

SELECT @test = JM.Project_Manager
FROM SPECTRUM.Spectrum.dbo.JC_JOB_MASTER_MC JM LEFT JOIN
     SPECTRUM.Spectrum.dbo.Z_EMPLOYEE_CODE_LIST ECL 
     ON LTRIM(RTRIM(JM.Project_Manager)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ECL.Employee_Code)) LEFT JOIN
     SPECTRUM.Spectrum.dbo.Z_EMPLOYEE_CODE_LIST ECL2 
     ON LTRIM(RTRIM(JM.Superintendent)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ECL2.Employee_Code))
WHERE JM.Company_Code = 'ABC' AND JM.Status_Code = 'A' AND JM.Job_Number = '29-0018-00';
```

In a `SELECT`, you can either assign variables or you can return a result set, but not both.  You may want other variables for the other columns.

Your code doesn't work because `JM` is not defined in a `SET` statement.  There is no connection to the previous `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

You need variable but table variable which can hold multiple `Project_Manager`s. So, this would be :

```
declare @projectmanager table  (
   Project_Manager varchar(255) )

insert into @projectmanager (Project_Manager)
     select JM.Project_Manager
     from . . . <rest part of query >;

select *
from @projectmanager;
```

For your current attempt `JM.Project_Manager` is actually missing. SQL Server can't find it as it is actually part of `SELECT` Statement. and the other thing is that you can't assign value to single variable in this way.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to insert the single value into a different table, so is there a better way to do this? For example, if the returned value of @projectmanager was '1234', I want to put that into a column in a different table.